# TYPO3 RealURL Language Domain Configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

We have following sceneario:

The website has 3 Domains.

- domain.de
- domain.eu
- domain.com.tr

TYPO3 is already setup for multilanguage and the IDs for the languages are:

- default (de) = 0
- en = 1
- tr = 2

Could somebody give us the proper RealURL configuration for this?

Comment: Could you please at least provide some of your effort on how to solve the issue by yourself? Just asking for someone else to do the configuration isn't exactly what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you just need to override default configuration for your other sub-domain.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array (
    'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
    'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1'
        ),
        'redirects' => array (
        ),
        'preVars' => array (
            '0' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'nc' => '0'
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            '1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => '0',
                    'en' => '1',
                    'tr' => '2'
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'rootpage_id' => '1'
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array (
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array (
            '_DEFAULT' => array (
                'archive' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[year]'
                    ),
                    '1' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[month]',
                        'valueMap' => array (
                            'january' => '01',
                            'february' => '02',
                            'march' => '03',
                            'april' => '04',
                            'may' => '05',
                            'june' => '06',
                            'july' => '07',
                            'august' => '08',
                            'september' => '09',
                            'october' => '10',
                            'november' => '11',
                            'december' => '12'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'page' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[pointer]'
                    ),
                ),
                'category' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[cat]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array (
                            'table' => 'tt_news_cat',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'article' => array (
                    '0' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array (
                            'table' => 'tt_news',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                                'strtolower' => '1',
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    '1' => array (
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[swords]'
                    ),
                ),                
            ),
        ),
        'fileName' => array (
            #'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => '.html',
            #'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
            'index' => array (
                'rss.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '100'
                    ),
                ),
                'rss091.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '101'
                    ),
                ),
                'rdf.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '102'
                    ),
                ),
                'atom.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '103'
                    ),
                ),
                'sitemap.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '776'
                    ),
                ),              
            ),
        ),
    )
);
/*
 * All your other domain configuration goes here. Change your domain name      
 * and domain root page id as per your need.
 * 
 */
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.de'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.de']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '41'; // Change your sub-domain root page id

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.eu'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.eu']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '51'; // Change your sub-domain root page id

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.com.tr'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain.com.tr']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '61'; // Change your sub-domain root page id
```

Please change codes as per your need. Hope this will help you.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Follow solution makes the language detection by domains:

```
<?php
  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = [
    'www.domain.de' => [ /* main configuration */,
    'www.domain.eu' => 'www.domain.de',
    'www.domain.tr' => 'www.domain.de',
    '_DOMAINS' => [
      'encode' => [
        [
          'GETvar' => 'L',
          'value' => '0',
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.de',
          'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domain.de'
        ],
        [
          'GETvar' => 'L',
          'value' => '1',
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.eu',
          'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domain.eu'
        ],
        [
          'GETvar' => 'L',
          'value' => '2',
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.tr',
          'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domain.tr'
        ]
      ],
      'decode' => [
        'www.domain.de' => [
          'GETvars' => [
            'L' => '',
          ],
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.de',
        ],
        'www.domain.eu'  => [
          'GETvars' => [
            'L' => '1',
          ],
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.eu',
        ],
        'www.domain.tr' => [
          'GETvars' => [
            'L' => '2',
          ],
          'useConfiguration' => 'www.domain.tr',
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below realurl configuration for multiple domain.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
  '_DEFAULT' =>
  array (
    'init' =>
    array (
      'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
    ),
    'pagePath' =>
    array (
      'rootpage_id' => '1',
    ),
    'fixedPostVars' => array(
    ),
    'fileName' =>
    array (
      'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
      'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
      'index' =>
      array (
        'print' =>
        array (
          'keyValues' =>
          array (
            'type' => 98,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'preVars' =>
    array (
      0 =>
      array (
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' =>
        array (
          'en' => '1',
          'tr' => '2'
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
      ),
    ),

    'postVarSets' =>array (
      '_DEFAULT' =>array (

      ),
    ),
  ),
);


$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.de'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.de'] ['pagePath'] ['rootpage_id'] = '1'; //Root Page Id

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.eu'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.eu'] ['pagePath'] ['rootpage_id'] = '169'; //Root Page Id

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.com.tr'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF'] ['realurl'] ['domain.com.tr'] ['pagePath'] ['rootpage_id'] = '386'; //Root Page Id
```